# IDA export settings hotkey

Tags: disassembly

People, good afternoon. Tell me please, can anyone know: how to export hotkey IDA? I understand - IDA saves these settings somewhere in the registry, but I can not find this place

Answer (score 2):

IDA doesn't stores hotkeys in registry rather it stores gui, terminal user interface(tui), analysis etc. related settings in configuration files which have `.cfg` extension, this approach provides flexibility in fine tuning/exporting configurations to user.

These configuration files are stored in `cfg/` directory which you can easily find in your IDA installation directory.
For example
`IDA_DIR/cfg/ida.cfg`

However, plugin related configurations are stored in  `IDA_DIR/plugins/plugins.cfg`

But the most important configuration files are those that govern the use of IDA and they are the following:

1. **ida.cfg** - stores most common configuration options (parsing/analysis/processors etc.)
2. **idagui.cfg** - applies to the graphical user interface (GUI behaviors, keyboard hotkey mappings etc.)
3. **idatui.cfg** - applies to the command line version of IDA (configuration for console version of IDA)

I assume you want to change or reuse your IDA hotkeys. Therefore, you can open `idagui.cfg` files in any text editor and change settings as per your preference.

All configuration files are well documented using comments and so does the `idagui.cfg` file, it has been divided into three sections:

- default GUI behaviors
- keyboard hotkey mappings
- File extension configuration for the `File->Open dialog`

However, if you do not feel comfortable editing `idagui.cfg` directly, then you should create `idauserg.cfg` in the same directory and add to it all of the options that you wish to override. In this case you only need to edit the last line in `idagui.cfg` to contains a directive to include `idauserg.cfg` file. For example:

`#softinclude <idauserg.cfg>`

Next time in case you upgrade/reinstall/use IDA on some other platform, you can simply copy `idauserg.cfg` into `cfg/` directory. Similar method can be applied for `ida.cfg` but user provided configuration file should be named as `idauser.cfg` and include directive in `ida.cfg` should be appended as above.